# Android autbahn websocket dead thread exception on initialization

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

Connection establishes. Exception raised. connection lost! Handlers on dead thread?
I havent sent any request and not done any handling OnMessageReceived.. Just initialized the websocket.

Log:

06-28 05:40:38.752: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): created
06-28 05:40:38.782: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): created
06-28 05:40:38.792: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(1306): WS reader created and started
06-28 05:40:38.792: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): running
06-28 05:40:38.792: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(1306): WS reader created and started
06-28 05:40:38.792: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): running
06-28 05:40:38.802: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter(1306): created
06-28 05:40:38.802: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(1306): WS writer created and started
06-28 05:40:38.812: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter(1306): created
06-28 05:40:38.812: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(1306): WS writer created and started
06-28 05:40:38.822: W/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): Status: 101 (Switching Protocols)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306): Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42de8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42de8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:503)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.notify(WebSocketReader.java:129)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.onHandshake(WebSocketReader.java:436)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.processHandshake(WebSocketReader.java:557)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.consumeData(WebSocketReader.java:629)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.run(WebSocketReader.java:659)
06-28 05:40:38.922: W/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): Status: 101 (Switching Protocols)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306): Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42e60} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42e60} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:503)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.notify(WebSocketReader.java:129)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.onHandshake(WebSocketReader.java:436)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.processHandshake(WebSocketReader.java:557)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.consumeData(WebSocketReader.java:629)
06-28 05:40:38.932: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.run(WebSocketReader.java:659)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306): Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42de8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42de8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:503)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.notify(WebSocketReader.java:129)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.onPing(WebSocketReader.java:456)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.processData(WebSocketReader.java:334)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.consumeData(WebSocketReader.java:625)
06-28 05:40:58.832: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.run(WebSocketReader.java:659)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306): Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42e60} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42e60} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:503)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.notify(WebSocketReader.java:129)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.onPing(WebSocketReader.java:456)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.processData(WebSocketReader.java:334)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.consumeData(WebSocketReader.java:625)
06-28 05:40:58.952: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.run(WebSocketReader.java:659)
06-28 05:41:08.842: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): run() : ConnectionLost
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306): Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42de8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42de8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:503)
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.notify(WebSocketReader.java:129)
06-28 05:41:08.862: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.run(WebSocketReader.java:665)
**06-28 05:41:08.862: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): ended**
06-28 05:41:08.952: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): run() : ConnectionLost
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306): Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42e60} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection$2) {b2d42e60} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:503)
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.notify(WebSocketReader.java:129)
06-28 05:41:08.972: W/MessageQueue(1306):   at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader.run(WebSocketReader.java:665)
**06-28 05:41:08.972: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): ended**

Comment: W/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(1306): Status: 101 (Switching Protocols) 06-28 05:40:38.922: Anyone explain this warning too ...

Comment: did you fix the problem? @chaitanyad